# Tiptap editor framework: what is the difference between set and toggle functions?

Tags: javascript, tiptap

I've been playing around with the tiptap editor framework for a few days now, and I have trouble understanding what is the difference between set and toggle functions. As an example, what is the difference between the `setBold()` function and the `toggleBold()` (https://tiptap.dev/api/marks/bold).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In general "toggle" means switch back-and-forth between on and off

So if you know you definitely want to switch bolding ON, use `.setBold()`

If you definitely want to switch bolding OFF, use `.unsetBold()`

And if you just want to reverse the bolding state, use `.toggleBold()`

#### Why you may have found it difficult to see the difference

If you tried both, and found identical effects, probably you were testing from a state of "not bolded".

If you try the two functions on a piece of text that is *already* bold, you will see that "toggle" turns off the bold, and "set" leaves the text remaining bold.